# If (Author) statement in Joomla 1.5

Tags: php, if-statement, joomla

i need php based if loop where i can in Joomla 1.5 HTML insert php code to find author and when i get that variable i can make IF statement

for example

```
if ($author="a") {
echo "This is author a";
}

elseif ($author="b"){
echo "this is author b";
}

elseif ($author="c"){
echo "this is author c";
}
```

I do not know how get $author variable (name) from article

Comment: Where are you inserting this code?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `==` or `===` instead of `=` in if statements

Example

```
if ($author == "a") {
    echo "This is author a";
} 

elseif ($author == "b") {
    echo "this is author b";
} 

elseif ($author == "c") {
    echo "this is author c";
}
```

Or Use Switch

```
switch ($author) {
    case "a" :
        echo "This is author a";
        break;
    case "b" :
        echo "This is author a";
        break;
    case "c" :
        echo "This is author a";
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thats ok but i do not know how get variable $author from system Joomla 1.5

I know how made IF statement just need to get variable name or ID of author:

ID of author is in DB jos_content in cell created_by